# Extract and reverse-engineer nefarious code from a TTF file

Tags: fonts

Based on [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91347/how-can-a-font-be-used-for-privilege-escalation) question here I understand that there is a way to embed code in fonts since the contours are essentially drawn using a Turing complete language.

The question is how would you identify this code and reverse-engineer it if it exists. The resources are particularly scarce on this subject. Are there specific step to be undertaken?

Comment: What do you mean "reverse engineer it"? Every half-decent font editor can show you exactly what it does, as it's all spec-compliant. Even [TTX](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) will happily show you what the code is doing "Whatever you need" with.

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenType Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/) provides all details necessary to read a TTF. And this derives from Apple's original [TrueType Specification](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/) (much of the information is duplicated across these two documents, but there are a few differences).

But reading the font data alone is not sufficient to determine whether a particular font file is "nefarious" or not. If you read the technical explanation of the exploit you linked to, you will see that it's not simply "nefarious code"; there are several other conditions necessary to trigger it:

- specially selected bytes in other font data tables
- execution under specific un-patched versions of Windows that execute font instructions in the kernel
- display of two specific glyphs at a particular size and in a particular sequence

There have been quite a few font-based exploits over the years, many of them having to do with execution of un-trusted code (user-installed fonts) in locations that assume trusted data/code. It's unlikely that anyone would be able to analyze a font alone and determine whether it is/isn't capable of a similar exploit; you'd really need to have a complete understanding of how the code is executed/how the data is processed in the target environment.

That said: it *is* possible to examine specific aspects of font data, and possibly even execute the TrueType instructions in a "safe" way (sandboxed/protected) to determine that there's something not quite right. The results of such an analysis might be sufficient evidence to make a decision to install such a font or not. There are some tools available for this already, such as [Microsoft's Font Validator](https://github.com/Microsoft/Font-Validator) (and a [fork](https://github.com/HinTak/Font-Validator/) that is being more actively developed).